# How does a complex wavefunction "hold" energy?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction

[Feynmann Lectures Vol 3 Ch 8 Sec 6](http://www.feynmanlectures.info/docroot/III_08.html#Ch8-S6) describes how an ammonia molecule can have two definite energy states.  If the amplitudes of the base states are

$ C_1(t) =\frac{a}{2}\,e^{-(i/\hbar)(E_0-A)t}+\frac{b}{2}\,e^{-(i/\hbar)(E_0+A)t}$

$C_2(t) =\frac{a}{2}\,e^{-(i/\hbar)(E_0-A)t}-\frac{b}{2}\,e^{-(i/\hbar)(E_0+A)t}$

then you get definite energy for either $a=0$ or $b=0$ ($a$ and $b$ being constants of integration).  In either of these states, $C_1$ and $C_2$ have a complex value that orbits the origin with time, but maintains a constant magnitude.  Thus, the probability of either state remains constant.

What I'm stuck with, is if these complex amplitudes only become physically manifest by being converted to probabilities (by taking the magnitude squared), then how can the wavefunctions 'hold' energy?  How does energy get in/out of the wavefunctions into things we can actually measure?

Finally what starting conditions would $a=0$ and $b=0$ correspond to?

Comment: The wavefunction doesn't 'hold' energy, whatever that may mean.

Comment: How does a real wavefunction hold energy?

Comment: In the sense that the state has a definite energy related to the exponential term in the amplitude of each base state.  But unless you can 'see' the complex numbers of the wavefunction you wouldn't know what that energy was.  Anything measurable will relate only to the probability, i.e. the square of the magnitude of the wavefunction, in which the oscillation is not apparent.  At least that's how I interpret it - if I didn't expect to be told I was wrong I wouldn't be asking!